# Can't see SMB directory in Mac Finder when logged in

Tags: linux, macos, samba

I setup SMB to show a "Media" section

```
[Media]
    path = /home/Share/Media
    writeable = yes
    browseable = yes
    valid users = stef
    guest ok = no
```

Currently, when I check the Shared entry on my mac, I see the shared computer. Clicking on it, I see "Connected as Guest" and the entry Media. If I click on it, it says "The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “Media” can’t be found." and I see no files. If I login as stef, I can access to both my home and the Media entry content.

The problem is that I would expect Media not to be visible when I'm accessing it as Guest, and to appear when I login as stef. I tried setting broseable to no, but now the situation is reversed, I can't see it either as guest or as logged in. Why?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things you can try:

Disable guest access to prevent anonymous browsing by editing the smb.conf file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Add this line to the [global] section:

```
restrict anonymous = 2
```

Also in System Preference > Sharing you can adjust the permissions for 'File Sharing' as you see fit.

As for things being reversed, that is odd. Maybe you should try reconfiguring the share again to see if you have the same issue. I know that configuration files can sometimes get mucked and it's sometimes easier to just re-create the smb share.